# Marketing Cloud Api Error

Tags: marketing-cloud, community, rest-api, error, marketingcloudapi

I am also facing same problem. not able to figure this out.
Also i gave all the permission inside installed package.

[image]
please help me

My request

```
Host: https://MY_SUBDOMAIN.rest.marketingcloudapis.com
POST /interaction/v1/events
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer MY_OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN

{
    "ContactKey": "abc123",
    "EventDefinitionKey":"MY_API_EVENTKEY",
}
```

**Error**

> Insufficient privileges to complete this action

Comment: Are you passing scope in your token call?

Comment: Not sure if this is the case but when you change permissions I've found it necessary to refresh the token in order to have the new permissions. You might want to make sure when you tested you weren't using an old token. And as @EasyE pointed out if you're passing scope in your call you can actually limit what you can do. I would suggest not passing scope because you have full permission to verify the call works. Then if necessary limit it down to the scope you actually need for the call if so desired.